# How to resize the textbox according to text value after clicking the submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, width

After entering value in the text box and pressing submit button, how to resize the textbox according to value inside. So the text center alignment displays properly(Using plain javascript or css).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div class="block">
    &#9728;
    <input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="Change City"></input>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>  
<style>
  .block{
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #inputValue{
    border: none;
  }
  #submit{
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script>
  var inputValue = document.querySelector("#inputValue");
  var submit = document.querySelector("#submit");

  inputValue.addEventListener("click",function(){
    submit.style.display = "block";
  });

  submit.addEventListener("click",function(){
    submit.style.display = "none";
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your reason for doing this? From a UX POV it seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: It,s feasible, but there are no **to go** solution for your problem.

Comment: You can get part way there by setting input to have text-align center (perhaps on the Submit). But I am unclear whether you actually want to shrink/grow the size of the input box or whether you just want the city to look centered, prefixed by the symbol. And what is it to look like if the user submits again (if this is allowed)? Incidentally, as that symbol is just for decoration it would probably be better as content on a label::before pseudo element rather than in the body of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I will give a example to you. Ge the idea from here

```
<input class="txt" id="inputBox" type="text"><br>
<button onClick=test()>test</button>

function test(){

    var getClass = document.querySelector( ".txt" );
    var getValue = document.getElementById("inputBox").value.length

    getClass.style.width = ((getValue + 1) * 8) + 'px';
 }
```

**As well as this is another way to do this , this will be better for you.**
[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/htymqbgc/24/)

```js
function test(){

    var getClass = document.querySelector( ".txt" );
  var getValue = document.getElementById("inputBox").value.length
  
  getClass.style.width = ((getValue + 1) * 8) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<input class="txt" id="inputBox" type="text"><br>
<button onClick=test()>
  test
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sun-icon is decorative and would therefore be suited to being in a CSS pseudo element rather than part of the main HTML.

It is not possible to add a pseudo before element to an input element, but we can give it a label and add the sun-icon in its before pseudo element.

```
label::before {
  content: '\2600';
  /* Unicode value for the HTML characer '&#9728';*/
}
```

We can also use this when the user clicks on submit. The text the user has input can become the label text - this will mean the user can select it if wanted, and can also click on it again to go back to edit it and submit (it is not clear from the question if this is what is required, but it seems logical to restore the input element on click).

```js
let inputValue = document.querySelector("#inputValue");
let submit = document.querySelector("#submit");
let label = document.querySelector("#label");

inputValue.addEventListener("click", function() {
  submit.style.display = "block";
  inputValue.style.display = "inline-block";
  label.innerHTML = '';
});

submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  submit.style.display = "none";
  label.innerHTML = inputValue.value;
  inputValue.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.block {
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

label::before {
  content: '\2600';
  /* Unicode value for the HTML characer '&#9728';*/
}

#inputValue {
  border: none;
}

#submit {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

  <label for="inputValue" id="label"></label>
  <input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="Change City" />

  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```